good day deployment errors BFFr.sol on sepolia
creation of BBFr pending...
creation of BBFr errored: Error occurred: revert.
revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.
tried to deploy after compile error for too much gas using remix
